# Page with two fqdn? Speedera.net

Tags: ssl

I have a page with a URL like this:

```
https://ssl1.speedera.net/www.abcd.net?resourceID=5
```

I don't understand the need for the ssl1.speedera.net part. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost certainly using a shared hosting service, which only offers SSL access via a single host name (`ssl1.speedera.net`), for which the host's certificate is set up. In this case `www.abcd.net` isn't really a host name, but just a directory (the convention is probably to use your host name as the directory name).

This is in general due to the fact that named virtual hosts are not as easy to set up. They require either adding your host name as an additional Subject Alternative Name in the shared host's certificate or additional configuration to support Server Name Indication for your host name via a different certificate (yours). Both these options would generally incur an additional cost, if offered at all by this provider.

Comment: Initially, I didn't understand your answer. I had to google around for all the terms/jargon and come back. Thank you.